# Reversing game experience formula to show how much experience a level needs

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I have a formula where I can calculate the character level for my game based on how much experience they have, like so:

```js
const calculateLevel = experience => {
    return ((Math.sqrt(625+100 * experience)-25) / 50);
}

console.log("50 XP is Level: " + calculateLevel(50));
console.log("150 XP is Level: " + calculateLevel(150));
console.log("659 XP is Level: " + calculateLevel(659));
console.log("3268 XP is Level: " + calculateLevel(3268));
```

But how can I reverse engineer this and calculate how much experience they have, using their level only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need to revert the specified function:

```
y = (sqrt(625 + 100 * x) - 25)/50 =>
x = ((50 * y + 25)^2 - 625) / 100
```

```js
const calculateExperience = level => {
    return (Math.pow(50 * level + 25, 2) - 625) / 100;
}

console.log("Level 1 is Experience: " + calculate_experience(1));
console.log("Level 2 is Experience: " + calculate_experience(2));
```